# Javascript Accordian

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a simple accordion working, except for one thing. I would like to be able to re-click the same accordion item again, and be able to set height to '0'.

Currently, the open accordion item closes when I click a different accordion item, which is exactly what I want to do — but I **also** want the ability to re-click the open accordion item and have that one close, when clicked. See working example below:

https://codepen.io/celli/pen/BaNLJWb

```
// set heights to 0
gsap.set('.content', {
  height: 0
});

// click function
$('.accordianItem').click(function() {

  if ($('.accordianItem').hasClass('on')) {
    gsap.to($('.content'), {
      duration: .25,
      height: 0
    });
    $('.accordianItem').removeClass('on');
  }

  gsap.to($(this).children('.content'), {
    duration: .25,
    height: "auto"
  });
  $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

What code can I add to add this extra functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code by adding another if that checks if the element clicked has 'on' class already. It should now work as you intended it to (hide when the user clicks on the already opened header).

```
// set heights to 0
gsap.set('.content', {height:0});

// click function
$('.accordianItem').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("on")){
       gsap.to($('.content'), {duration:.25, height:0});
       $('.accordianItem').removeClass('on');
    }
    else{
      if ($('.accordianItem').hasClass('on')) {
         gsap.to($('.content'), {duration:.25, height:0});
         $('.accordianItem').removeClass('on');
      }
      gsap.to($(this).children('.content'), {duration:.25, height:"auto"});
      $(this).addClass('on');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this *much* more simply than how you're currently doing it:

```
// Create the animation that you need
const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true});
tl.to('.content', {duration: 0.25, height:0});

// Set the timeline to its end state
tl.progress(1);

// Toggle the timeline's direction
$('.accordianItem').click(function() {
    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
});
```

### [Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/KKpgRYM?editors=0010)

I highly recommend checking out [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/). They're super useful and you can get quick help from people who are experts in GSAP and web animation :)